Issue adding custom Definition in google analytics
How to resolve this issue 'Parameter name is not allowed for this scope.' while creating a custom dimension for google analytics.
steps:

open firebase console
select Analytics on the left side menu
select 'Custom definitions'
on the right side click 'Create custom dimension'
fill all field and while adding value in 'Event parameter' save button disabled, and while we click we can see the error.

